# UIImage with border. Invalid Context 0x0

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, core-graphics, cgcontext

I'm fetching an image and saving it to temporary directory in a background thread. Before saving, I want to add a little white border to this UIImage. I'm doing this:

```
    - (UIImage *)imageWithBorder:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale); {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer (context, NULL);
        //Draw
        [image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 10);
        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(context);
    }
    UIImage *result =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Everything is okay, after loading that image from a temporary directory I can see border on an image, but in console I'm getting `invalid context 0x0` when the code below implements. What's wrong here?

---

**Update 01**

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithBorder:(UIImage *)image {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale); {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextDrawImage (context, rect, [image CGImage]);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 10);
    }
    UIImage *result =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
[image drawInRect:rect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
```

to

```
CGContextDrawImage (context, rect, [image CGImage]);
```

Also, why use a transparency layer? You have the alpha set to 1, so you could just overwrite the original image, no?

EDIT: I just ran the same code in my app, on the background, it worked flawlessly:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithBorder:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSLog(@"Thread %@", [NSThread currentThread]);

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Draw
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, [image CGImage]);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextStrokeRectWithWidth(context, rect, 10);
    UIImage *result =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
assert(result);
    return result;
}
```

When I do this in viewDidAppear: (but its a small image, maybe the size is relevant?)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{ [self imageWithBorder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"02-redo.png"]] ; } );
```

this is all I see in the log:

```
2012-08-27 13:48:04.679 Searcher[32825:11103] Thread <NSThread: 0x6d30e30>{name = (null), num = 4}
```

So something else is going on with you code. I'm building with Xcode 4.4.1, deployment target is 5.1

EDIT: In your block, you cannot refer to "cell" as cell is temporal - with recycling it may not even be visible. So the image name will be routed through a local NSString, then at the end, you need another method that the image can be posted to, along with the cell indexPath. That method will see if that indexPath is in the visibleCells of the table, if so then update the image, if not you want to store the image so it can be used with the tableView next asks for the cell.

EDIT2: This code:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 
  UIImage *image = [_thumbnailMaster thumbnailForItemWithFilename:cell.label.text];
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ cell.thumbnailView.image = image; }); 
});
```

Should be turned into something that does not involve "cell" as cell may go out of scope or be used by another index (assuming recycling). Something like this:

```
NSString *text = cell.label.text;
NSIndexPath *path = ...;

dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 
  UIImage *image = [_thumbnailMaster thumbnailForItemWithFilename:text];  
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self updateCellImage:image withPath"path]; }); 
});
```

Your method determines if that cell is visible, if so update the image, if not save it so next time you need it you have it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Transparency layer is not necessary here. Thanks.

Comment: Let me (us) know if the CGContextDrawImage gets rid of the warning. Also, you should NOT have to move this to the main thread if you use all CGCOntext messages - or so everyone keeps saying on the Apple lists. Everyone keeps saying UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() is threadsafe as of iOS4 I believe, even if the docs do not reflect it.

Comment: Very strange problem... Yes. I got invalid context on CGContextDrawImage. An even with that, I got right image. Also, when I write UIGraphicsPushContext, it all just freezes  O_O

Comment: You removed the transparency layer code? Also, there is no "UIGraphicsPushContext" above...

Comment: Update your code to show exactly what you are using right now.

Comment: Updated the question. Can't post code right here in comments.

Comment: I'm getting SIGABRT on `assert(result);` Don't know what's wrong. In table view, cellForRowAtIndexPath. I do this `dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImage *image = [_thumbnailMaster thumbnailForItemWithFilename:cell.label.text];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.thumbnailView.image = image;
        }); });` and that's it. _thumbnailMaster making a thumbnail of an image file, then it should add a border to that thumbnail, but he does it with this errors :(

Comment: Your problem is "cell.label.text" - add a NSString value above the dispatch, set the image title there, then use that local variable in your block. The assert is telling you that no image was created, probably because no image was passed in.

Comment: Damn. I was getting SIGABRT when it tried to make a thumbnail from a file that's not an image. Now it's OK. About your last edit: you want to say, that I should store indexPath in the thumbnail maker class, make the main View Controller the delegate of that thumbnail maker, and then call delegate method from thumbnail maker to check and update the cell?

Comment: Alright, I did it, and it works just fine. Thank you very much for your time :) You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

> UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext Returns the current graphics context.
>
> CGContextRef UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext (    void ); Return Value The
>   current graphics context.
>
> Discussion The current graphics context is nil by default. Prior to
>   calling its drawRect: method, view objects push a valid context onto
>   the stack, making it current. If you are not using a UIView object to
>   do your drawing, however, you must push a valid context onto the stack
>   manually using the UIGraphicsPushContext function.
>
> You should call this function from the main thread of your application
>   only.

This is from [UIKit Function Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)